# Реализация авторизации/аутентификации для микросервисов

Tags: python, безопасность, архитектура, авторизация, аутентификация

Никогда не делал ручками авторизацию/аутентификацию. Понадобилось. Цельной картинки не сложилось, поэтому я задаю этот вопрос, чтобы породить немного материала и самому разобраться в проблеме.

Кратко. У нас нет чёткого разделения на авторизацию и аутентификацию. Иными словами, если пользователь получил аутентификация, то у него есть и авторизация для всех ресурсов. Кроме того, мы не используем сессии и делаем максимально просто, насколько возможно.

Примерная архитектура. Есть backend, есть frontend. Они между собой общаются. Backend каждый раз, при запросе с frontend идёт на сервер авторизации и спрашивает, есть ли доступ у юзера к бэку или нет. Сервис авторизации отвечает: 200 или 403. Разумеется, есть регистрация и есть логин. Об этом ниже.

[image: architecture]

Есть 3 endpoint:

- register/
- login/
- validate/

Отметим, что у нас нет возможности logout/. Эта проблема решается удалением токена на фронте из localstorage браузера.

## Login

[image: login endpoint]

1 . frontend отправляет запрос на аутентификацию (логин). Пароль и логин прилетают в открытом виде (это плохо, но сейчас нас это не заботит). Система маленькая и атаки вряд ли будут на текущем этапе.

2 . backend получает логин и пароль, их конкатенирует, а затем, с помощью 
следующего кода получает хэш (я привожу конкретные [либы](https://palletsprojects.com/p/werkzeug/), чтобы не было не понимания). Под капотом sha256:

```
>>> from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash
>>> hash = generate_password_hash('foobar')
>>> hash
>>> 'pbkdf2:sha256:50000$vT9fkZM8$04dfa35c6476acf7e788a1b5b3c35e217c78dc04539d295f011f01f18cd2175f'
```

3 . Этот хэш сравнивается с тем хэшем, который уже есть в БД с помощью соответствующей функции:

```
>>> from werkzeug.security import check_password_hash
>>> check_password_hash(hash, 'foobar')
>>> True
```

4 . Затем, в заголовке пользователю отдаётся `token` в поле `token` и `_id` в поле `_id`. Я знаю, что обычно его кладут в куки, но не знаю, зачем мне это надо. Поэтому просто в отдельном поле заголовке. В данном случае, токен -- это хэш, который мы получили выше. Этот токен мы в дальнейшем отправляем вместе с любым запросом к бэку, чтобы он был отправлен в сервис авторизации и прошёл валидацию.

## Validate

[image: validate endpoint]

1. Валидация требуется всякий раз, когда к бэку приходит запрос.
2. Тогда, бэк берёт из хэдера _id и отправляет всё это в сервис авторизации/аутентификации.
3. Сервис авторизации сравнивает то, что ему прислал бэк с тем, что лежит в бд с помощью функции сравнения хэшей. Хэш достаёт по _id из БД.

## Register

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Регистрация оборачивается в мьютекс (трапеция на блок-схеме).

## Вопросы

- Какие недостатки Вы здесь видите? Меня интересует как безопасность, так и вопрос дальнейшего роста. Сейчас в приоритете безопасность.
- Я много раз видел, что люди используют jwt-token, но мне кажется, что это достаточно сложный формат и использовать его правильно не так просто как кажется.
- Хорошо ли отдавать на фронт хэш, который указан выше 'pbkdf2:sha256:50000$vT9fkZM8$04dfa35c6476acf7e788a1b5b3c35e217c78dc04539d295f011f01f18cd2175f'? Это безопасно или из него можно что-то украсть?

P.s. Отмечу, что на фронте не фигурирует email или password юзера. Они обитают только в БД (пароль шифрован). На фронт отдаётся _id юзера из БД, а также token, как указано выше. Эта пара призвана аутентифицировать юзера при каждом обращении к бэку. Т.е. при каждом походе к бэку, летит запрос в сервис авторизации.

Comment: Хэш можно запихнуть в видеокарту и подобрать пароль. Если он несложный — то за относительно небольшое время.

Comment: @andreymal в хэше не обязательно содержится пароль - да и зачем? Есть еще и хеши на одну сессию.

Comment: Раз уж Дух поднял вопрос, то немного поною в комментах: я однажды обнаружил, что один из моих паролей (между прочим, очень сложный!) был успешно подобран из вот такого хэша проектом hashes.org (который для быстрого вскрытия использовал большую сеть компьютеров волонтёров)

Answer (score 0):

К Вашему вопросу могу сказать, зачем токен кладут в куки, и обязательно с атрибутом Http-Only: это для того, чтобы javascript не имел доступа к токену. С одной стороны, тогда разработчики фронта избавляются от необходимости продумывать механизмы его хранения и доставки, с другой - никакая XSS не сможет "украсть" вашу авторизацию. Это несколько сложнее в реализации на бэке, поэтому в обучающих примерах так не делают. Но как только приложение становится реально используемым, настоятельно рекомендуется переехать на куки HttpOnly

Comment: Если хэш делать на сессию и не криптовать в нем реальные данные, то ведь это будет не менее надёжно, чем в кукисах его хранить?